# How to display word 2007 document in web browser control using asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, browser

I am using VS -2010 for my asp.net web application.Now i want to display word 2007 document on browser.So, i decided to use webbrowser control for displaying word 2007 document.
But i did not find the component in tool box. So, could you guide me to get the add the web browser control and how to show a word 2007 document in the web browser control.

Otherwise, please suggest some other better approach for displaying word 2007 document in browser(Read Only Mode)?

Answer (score 2):

**Try To Refer Following Code:**

```
object oDocument;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 string sFileName;
 openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
 openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
 sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

 if (sFileName.Length!=0)
 {
 oDocument = null;
 webBrowser1.Navigate(sFileName);
 }
 }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 openFileDialog1.Filter = "Office Documents " + " " + "(*.doc, *.xls, *.ppt)|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt";
 openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

 }

 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
 oDocument = webBrowser1.Document;

 }
```

**Referance Link:**

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/153951/opening-worddoc2007-inside-webbrowserc-sharp-net.aspx

Comment: How to add web browser control in the project

Comment: step by step shown over here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET